# Declare ampersand in DTD?

Tags: xml, doctype, dtd, ampersand, dita

When transforming some xml (dita) documents there is a problem with special characters, ampersand and the "less than" character (<). But to take the ampersand as the example, what is happening is that it is repeated several times in the output for some reason. The thing is, I discovered that if `&amp;` is replaced (directly in the xml content) with `&#38;` then it works fine, no repetitions.

I don't know what is causing this, but what I want to do is to declare the ampersand in the DTD to replace it with `&#38;`. I found by googling that you should do that like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN" "concept.dtd" [
 <!ENTITY amp "&#38;#38;">
]>
```

For simplicity, I'm including inline entity declaration here, but I also tried declaring it in the actual DTD (concept.dtd). But it doesn't work. It doesn't even seem to kick in, because I tried replacing it with `<!ENTITY amp "TEST">` as well, just to see if it did anything at all, and it didn't.

So how do I do this? I just want the `&amp;` to be replaced by `&#38`; so I don't have to manually replace every occurrence in every document...

Comment: Which XML parser are you using? It might be one that doesn't support internal entities at all -- which would hardly be conforming, but there you go; `&amp;` and `&lt;` are supposed to be predefined and work even without an explicit declaration anyway.

Comment: It's the DITA Open Toolkit 1.4.3, and it uses Saxon 6.5. Yes, I know it's supposed to be predefined and work, and it does turn it into &, but unfortunately multiple instances of &. That's the problem... But if I replace &amp; with &#38; it isn't multiplied.

Comment: Are you sure that you're modifying the correct DTD? You said below that you're using oXygen; have you checked the catalog file to see what DTD the `-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN` public identifier is mapped to?

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure, I'm not using the bundled DITA OT in Oxygen, though, I'm pointing it to the client's older 1.4.3 version. And in that catalog-dita.xml file I have checked and rechecked the DTD mapping... I also tried declaring the entity inline as described in the question above. And just to be sure I used a local dtd placed in the same folder corresponding to the system id in the doctype declaration... Nothing works!

Comment: Does this occur in every time an ampersand is used anywhere in a DITA document, or only in some specific cases (like only in attributes or only in conrefferd content etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from Oxygen support. Not sure this helps anyone, it's rather an unusual situation... But the xercesImpl.jar library from the custom DITA OT had to be included in the transformation scenario. Then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an XML processing pipeline that does the right thing with `&#38;` and the wrong thing with `&amp;`, then you have a broken XML processing pipeline.  Something in your code is bungling the ampersands.  You should fix the code rather than trying to work around it by modifying your XML documents.

Comment: I don't doubt that you're right there is something wrong in the pipeline, but like I commented @Henning I'm using the DITA Open Toolkit 1.4.3, and it's not my choice, it's the client. They will be upgrading eventually, and this problem will go away, but until then I need a fix without having to modify the entire DITA Open Toolkit. I should also mention that the transformations are just for drafts, but still important to get the proper output.

Comment: So that's why I'm trying to find a workaround, even if there is something wrong in the pipeline of the toolkit... I just don't understand why I can't replace the &amp; with an entity in the dtd, is it not possible to "override" predefined entities?

Comment: I seriously doubt that the DITA Open Toolkit gets this wrong.  Do you have any custom code at all in this pipeline?  Something the client might have written?  That's where the error lies.

Comment: I'm testing it without any customization, in order to get to the root of the problem and eliminate any errors that I might have introduced in the customization, so no customization per se. However, I did have to do quite a bit of configuration of libraries etc in Oxygen (with their guidance) to make DITA OT 1.4.3 work in Oxygen 12.1 (which is normally adapted to 1.5.1). That may be the cause of the problem in the pipeline. However, I still need a workaround until the client upgrades to a later OT that works by default with Oxygen.